# Can I alias a person in irssi?

Tags: irssi

Basically I want to change the name displayed for a certain user.  Can this be done with IRSSI?  If so how?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write a plugin script to do this. A good starting point might be the [tracknick](http://scripts.irssi.org/html/tracknick.pl.html) plugin.

Comment: I guess I'll write it myself then :-)